# Re-size top becomes inaceessible with display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

this is the skeleton of my problem, when my input errors are displayed the top is inaccessible. I need to align in the center, both vertical and horizontal. Sometimes the card has a lot of inputs and sometimes not, when it doesn't have to be in the center.

if I remove the "align-items: center;" the problem solves, but it is not aligned. I've tried using "margin: auto;" but it didn't work either.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url(../img/bg.png) center no-repeat;
}

.card {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  height: max-content;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 42px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #cecece;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

input {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 1">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 2">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 3">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 4">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 5">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 6">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 7">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 8">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

it is not possible to visualize input 1 ... the top and bottom margins simulate when errors are displayed. When the "card" expands, the top becomes inaccessible.

[image]

Comment: _“when my input errors are displayed”_ - me no see, in exampl-ee …

Comment: the issue of errors is an example .... when I submit and there is a field with an error, the "card" expands, causing the above not to be seen.

Comment: Then provide us with a proper [mre] that shows _that_ situation.

Comment: I added "margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;" in the input tag to simulate an expansion. If you open it in the browser, you will see that you cannot see input 1.

Comment: _“if I remove the "align-items: center;" the problem solves”_ - same, if you just stop absolutely positioning `.card` – so do just that then …?

Comment: it worked ... thank you very much. I had to remove the overflow on the body too ... I'll see a way to add the image in the background without having to use the absolut on the card.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is what you're looking for I made some edit in codes and now it is working will the page is shrunk and child elements `input` are not overflowing

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url(../img/bg.png) center no-repeat;
}

.card {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  height: max-content;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 42px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #cecece;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 1">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 2">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 3">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 4">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 5">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 6">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 7">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="test 8">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```